# Where can python cached script files be located, and how can I flush them?

Tags: python, caching

I have a python project that periodically throws the following error:

```
Running jobs:
         RollingRewalkTriggersBase True 2019-03-17 18:44:47.772462 2018-12-10 13:05:47.977925 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runScheduler.py", line 93, in doCall
    self._doCall()
  File "runScheduler.py", line 110, in _doCall
    instance._go()
  File "/media/Storage/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/WebMirror/TimedTriggers/TriggerBase.py", line 44, in _go
    self.go()
  File "/media/Storage/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/WebMirror/TimedTriggers/RollingRewalkTriggers.py", line 175, in go
    self.retrigger_other()
  File "/media/Storage/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/WebMirror/TimedTriggers/RollingRewalkTriggers.py", line 124, in retrigger_other
    for chunk in pbar:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 991, in __iter__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1088, in close
    self._decr_instances(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 446, in _decr_instances
    if inst.pos > abs(instance.pos):
AttributeError: 'tqdm' object has no attribute 'pos'
```

The problem here is that:

- `/media/Storage/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/` doesn't exist (it's been moved to `/media/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/`)
- `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/` Doesn't exist (I've switched from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, which only has python 3.6).
- I"m running on `pypy3`, not cpython.
- The `tqdm` source code referenced in the error doesn't match the files on-disk (the library has been updated, and the line numbers point to code that doesn't match the error output).

I have *no* idea where the error is coming from. I've *reinstalled the freaking OS*, and it's still there.

Now, `/media/NNNN` is a network drive that wasn't reinstalled, so I tried to clean out any potential `*.pyc` files:

From `/media/Scripts/ReadableWebProxy/`:

- `find . -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rv \{\} \;`
- `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`

At this point, I flat out don't understand what's going on. I'm getting error messages from a previous version of the project, and I can't seem to fix them. I don't understand where the offending files could possibly be cached, considering that the entire OS has been reinstalled, and any `*.pyc` files have been deleted.

Given the above context, basically, the question is "Where can python stick cached compilation files"? Something, *somewhere* seems to be referring to a file that doesn't even exist any more, and I've been unable to force python to refresh it's compilation cache.